# TOR, Irssi and Hidden Services - how? (2019)

Tags: torsocks

I am trying to connect to a hidden-service-IRC via torsocks and Irssi, following this [guide](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO/irssi) - however, it seems rather outdated and doesnt work as excpected.

It is important to note, that torsocks itself works flawlessly, `torsocks curl ipinfo.io/ip` shows connection via TOR, also connecting via torsocks and Irssi to clearweb-IRCs works. But connecting to a hidden service doesn't.

Following the linked guide, adding networks (but ignoring the --network switch wich Irssi seems to have dropped) results in the following er after `/connect Server1`:

```
ERROR torsocks[15494]: Unable to resolve. Status reply: 4 (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply()
```

And Irssi itself states: `16:47 -!- Irssi: Unable to connect server Server1 port 6667 [Non-recoverable failure in name resolution]`

Trying to connect to the URL itself via `/connect $URL.onion 6667` without adding the server/network to Irssi before results in: `WARNING torsocks[15492]: [connect] Connection to a local address are denied since it might be a TCP DNS query to a local DNS server. Rejecting it for safety reasons. (in tsocks_connect() at connect.`

Is there anything I can do to get this working?

Comment: we recommend https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng as a wrapper instead of torsocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed a workaround for this problem using `socat`:

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:4223,fork SOCKS4A:localhost:URL.onion:PORT,socksport=9050
```

with this, one can connect to the specified hidden-service-IRC from within Irssi via `/connect localhost 4223`